# Why can't I navigate through array of custom objects?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following Interface in angular:

```
export interface Example{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  num1: number;
  num2: number;
  num3: number;
}
```

I also have a Service where I call an API and obtain a result, and I iterate the result to initialize an array of the interface above:

```
res: any;
examples: Example[]
...
this.service.getData().subscribe(response => 
 {
   res = response;
 
   res.feed.entry.forEach((item: any) => {
     examples.push({
       id: item.id
       name: item.name
       ...
       });
```

When I call this service and I console.log the result, I get an array of objects with the following structure:

```
Array []
 0: Object {
    id: someID
    name: someName
    num1: 1
    num2: 2
    num3: 3
}
...
```

I get an array with around 50 elements as return with the same structure. The problem comes when I try to do a `.forEach` from that array. The forEach is 'skipped', I put console.log inside and nothing shows. I try to call it as follows:

```
this.examples.forEach((item)=>{
  console.log(item);
}
```

But nothing shows. How can I iterate the array to work with the information within? Why is this happening?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to iterate through `this.examples`? within the `subscribe` or outside of `subscribe`?

Comment: Please supply more from your code, the big picture is unclear

Comment: @Andres2142 I am trying to iterate on the ```ngOnInit``` right after I call my service.

Comment: Edit: Also when I try to access this.examples[0] with console.log the result is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of the fact that you populate your array inside the `subscribe` function.
If you iterate your array right after the subscription, there is a change that the subscription isn't yet finished or started and therefore you don't have any element inside your array.
To check this, put the iteration of the array with the `console.log` of it rignt after the `res.feed.entry.forEach` inside the subscription.